# Updating plot and table data simultaneously within a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, dt

I have some data and I'm trying to visualize each observation line by line (one line per second) using both a plot (`plotly`) and a table (`DT`) simultaneously. I have no problem getting each object to update independently, however I haven't found a proper way to update both at the same time. Here is what I've been trying :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

df <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=1000, ncol=1)  # Data

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(align = "center",
      actionButton("button", "Start")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      column(width=6,
        plotlyOutput("plot")
      ),
      column(width=6,
        dataTableOutput("table")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues (step = 1)           # Row index

  # Static Table
  output$table  <- renderDataTable({
    t(as.matrix(df[values$step, ]))  # First observation only
  })  

  # Static Plot
  p <- plot_ly(
    y = as.numeric(df[1, ]),  # First observation only
    type = "scatter",
    mode = 'lines'
  )
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(p)

  # Updating plot and table
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    time_0 <- Sys.time()  # Initial time

    while(TRUE){
      Sys.sleep(1)

      values$step <- difftime(Sys.time(), time_0, units="secs")  # Counting seconds since button hit

      dataTableProxy("table", session) %>%  # Table doesn't update
        replaceData(t(as.matrix(df[values$step, ])))

      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%  # Plot does update
        plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(df[values$step, ]))), list(0))

    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I place the `dataTableProxy` call outside of the `observeEvent` and within its own `observe` it will update as expected (updating the value each second), however it will stop updating as soon as I hit the "Start" button. Then only the plot will update, that's why I thought it would be better if I placed all updates within the same `observeEvent`, but now only the plot is getting updated.  Why is it that the table values aren't updating even though  `values$step` is changing every second?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a scoping issue (change `t(as.matrix(df[1, ]))` for `t(as.matrix(df[values$step, ]))` to see the difference). I found another way of handling this by updating  `values$step` within its own `observe`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

df <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=1000, ncol=1)  # Data

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel("Empty panel"),

    mainPanel(
      column(width=6,
        plotlyOutput("plot")
      ),
      column(width=6,
        dataTableOutput("table")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues (step = 1)  # Row index

  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)

    isolate({
    values$step <- values$step + 1  # Updates after 1 second
    })
  })

  # Static Table
  output$table  <- renderDataTable({
    t(as.matrix(df[1, ]))  # First observation only
  })  

  # Static Plot
  p <- plot_ly(
    y = as.numeric(df[1, ]),  # First observation only
    type = "scatter",
    mode = 'lines'
  )
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(p)

  # Updating plot and table
  observe({

    dataTableProxy("table", session) %>%  # Table doesn't update
      replaceData(t(as.matrix(df[values$step, ])))

    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%  # Plot does update
      plotlyProxyInvoke("extendTraces", list(y=list(list(df[values$step, ]))), list(0))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```